# No comprendo porque me da este error en esa lines

Tags: mysql, windows-forms, .net

Estoy trabajando en un formulario de windows forms conectado a una base de datos en xampp mysql

```
public static int ObtenerAlumnoMax(){
            MySqlConnection conexion = Datos.ObtenerConexion();
            MySqlCommand _comando = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT MAX(id_estudiante) FROM estudiante "), conexion);
            MySqlDataReader _reader = _comando.ExecuteReader();
            _reader.Read();
            int variable = _reader.GetInt32(0);//Aca me da el error y es este: System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.'
            conexion.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("valor: " + variable);
            return variable;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! tu pregutna esta incompleta no? usa el boton [edit] y completala.. Ni mysql ni xampp parecen relevante a lo poco que escribiste... podrias dejar en claro cual es el problema?

Comment: Salidos Kevin, y bienvenido a SO. También debes incluir el mensaje de error que aparece al ejecutar el código. ¿Qué mensaje sale en la pantalla o consola? Adicionalmente, podrías redactar el titulo de la pregunta como: "Al ejecutar mi consulta SQL desde .NET me aparece el mensaje 'XXXX ", así más personas podrían interesarse en leerla y ayudarte.